# Strange crashes with message "Attempted to dereference garbage pointer"

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, crash-reports

My app is ARC abide app but still I see multiple crashes with message "Attempted to de-reference garbage pointer" in the crash report. They are hard to diagnose.

My question is why application is crashing because of memory issues even after we are on ARC and we are not able to reproduce it with same steps. How to tackle such crashes?

One such crash report is as below:

> CrashReporterKey: 896d0c8676c0e02eb292865a654825359de4d427
>   HardwareModel: iPod4,1 Version: 5510 (3.0.0) OSVersion: iPhone OS
>   6.1.3 (10B329) Date/Time: 2013-08-15 09:50:51.000 -0700 FirmwareVersion: 2.27.0 Report Version:  104
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes:
>   KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x31fd4078 Crashed Thread:  0
>
> Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0
>   Crashed: 0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b1ac5b0 objc_msgSend +
>   16 1   UIKit                           0x3533c350 0x35338000 + 17232 2
>   UIKit                           0x3533b6c8 0x35338000 + 14024 3
>   UIKit                           0x3533b118 0x35338000 + 12568 4
>   GraphicsServices                0x3702d5a0 0x37027000 + 26016 5
>   GraphicsServices                0x3702d1d0 0x37027000 + 25040 6
>   CoreFoundation                  0x33508170 0x33471000 + 618864 7
>   CoreFoundation                  0x33508110 0x33471000 + 618768 8
>   CoreFoundation                  0x33506f98 0x33471000 + 614296 9
>   CoreFoundation                  0x33479eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
>   10  CoreFoundation                  0x33479d48 CFRunLoopRunInMode +
>   104 11  GraphicsServices                0x3702c2e8 GSEventRunModal +
>   72 12  UIKit                           0x3538f300 UIApplicationMain +
>   1120 13  MyApp                          0x000a8e58 main + 20
>
> Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager Thread
>   1: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b69f648 kevent64 + 24 1
>   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b5cadf8 0x3b5c7000 + 15864
>
> Thread 2 name:  WebThread Thread 2: 0   WebCore
>   0x39503560 0x3945d000 + 681312 1   WebCore
>   0x394e7f90 0x3945d000 + 569232 2   WebCore
>   0x394e2788 0x3945d000 + 546696 3   WebCore
>   0x396ca8a8 _ZN7WebCore11FrameLoader16detachFromParentEv + 64 4
>   WebKit                          0x39e12618 0x39d8d000 + 546328 5
>   WebCore                         0x394699c8 0x3945d000 + 51656 6
>   WebKit                          0x39e12490 0x39d8d000 + 545936 7
>   WebKit                          0x39e18570 0x39d8d000 + 570736 8
>   WebKit                          0x39e184a8 0x39d8d000 + 570536 9
>   WebCore                         0x394fb850 0x3945d000 + 649296 10 
>   CoreFoundation                  0x33508680 0x33471000 + 620160 11 
>   CoreFoundation                  0x33507ee8 0x33471000 + 618216 12 
>   CoreFoundation                  0x33506cb0 0x33471000 + 613552 13 
>   CoreFoundation                  0x33479eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
>   14  CoreFoundation                  0x33479d48 CFRunLoopRunInMode +
>   104 15  WebCore                         0x39467500 0x3945d000 + 42240
>   16  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b608310 0x3b5f7000 + 70416
>
> Thread 3 name:  CommRunLoop Thread Thread 3: 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b6af6a4 __semwait_signal + 24 1
>   Foundation                      0x33decc60 0x33d99000 + 343136 2
>   MyApp                          0x002be680 -[CommRunLoop
>   runLoopThread:] + 504 3   Foundation                      0x33e49e80
>   0x33d99000 + 724608 4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b608310
>   0x3b5f7000 + 70416
>
> Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private Thread 4: 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b6af594 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20 1 
>   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b608310 0x3b5f7000 + 70416
>
> Thread 5: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b6af6a4
>   __semwait_signal + 24 1   Foundation                      0x33decc60 0x33d99000 + 343136 2   MyApp                          0x00333580
>   -[KSCrashDeadlockMonitor runMonitor] + 244 3   Foundation                      0x33e49e80 0x33d99000 + 724608 4   libsystem_c.dylib
>   0x3b608310 0x3b5f7000 + 70416
>
> Thread 6 name:  KSCrash Exception Handler (Secondary) Thread 6: 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b69eeb4 mach_msg_trap + 20 1
>   MyApp                          0x0032f710 ksmachexc_i_handleExceptions
>   + 124 2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b608310 0x3b5f7000 + 70416
>
> Thread 7 name:  KSCrash Exception Handler (Primary) Thread 7:
>
> Thread 8 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader Thread 8: 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b69eeb4 mach_msg_trap + 20 1
>   CoreFoundation                  0x33508040 0x33471000 + 618560 2
>   CoreFoundation                  0x33506da0 0x33471000 + 613792 3
>   CoreFoundation                  0x33479eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
>   4   CoreFoundation                  0x33479d48 CFRunLoopRunInMode +
>   104 5   Foundation                      0x33dc63d0 0x33d99000 + 185296
>   6   Foundation                      0x33e49e80 0x33d99000 + 724608 7
>   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b608310 0x3b5f7000 + 70416
>
> Thread 9 name:  JavaScriptCore::BlockFree Thread 9: 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b6af08c __psynch_cvwait + 24 1
>   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b600aa0 pthread_cond_timedwait + 40
>   2   JavaScriptCore                  0x37422c70
>   _ZN3WTF15ThreadCondition9timedWaitERNS_5MutexEd + 104 3   JavaScriptCore                  0x37534550 0x373c7000 + 1496400 4
>   JavaScriptCore                  0x37546fa8 0x373c7000 + 1572776 5
>   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b608310 0x3b5f7000 + 70416
>
> Thread 10 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.background-priority
>   Thread 10: 0   MyApp                          0x00320a18
>   +[KSCrashReportFilterAppleFmt filterWithReportStyle:] + 0 1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b5c9118 0x3b5c7000 + 8472 2
>   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b5d7258 0x3b5c7000 + 66136 3
>   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b5d73b8 0x3b5c7000 + 66488 4
>   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b5fda10 0x3b5f7000 + 27152
>
> Thread 11: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b6afd98
>   __workq_kernreturn + 8 1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b5fda10 0x3b5f7000 + 27152
>
> Thread 12: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b6afd98
>   __workq_kernreturn + 8 1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b5fda10 0x3b5f7000 + 27152
>
> Thread 13: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b6afd98
>   __workq_kernreturn + 8 1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b5fda10 0x3b5f7000 + 27152
>
> Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
>       r0: 0x1fd2a130     r1: 0x357e82c0     r2: 0x1fd3a6d0     r3: 0x20a8a4a0 
>       r4: 0x31fd4070     r5: 0x20a8a4a0     r6: 0x2fd59a10     r7: 0x2fd599f8 
>       r8: 0x20a8af20     r9: 0x0d5fa0b0    r10: 0xbecb6c00    r11: 0x1fd3a6d0 
>       ip: 0x3bb2bd64     sp: 0x2fd599c8     lr: 0x355abb97     pc: 0x3b1ac5b0    cpsr: 0x20000030
>
> Extra Information:
>
> Stack Dump (0x2fd599a0-0x2fd59a18):
>
> A8B4BC3B209FF240B499D52FADD81A3BA8B4BC3BC099D52F45D91A3BD0A6D31FC899D52FF1D01B3BA0A4A820D0A6D31F000000000020B23F00000000806DD9BF00000000E073ECBF0000000000000000009F63BF209FF240789AD52F51C3333500000000806DD9BF00000000E073ECBFDA1B7C21209FF240
>
> Notable Addresses: {
>       "r1": {
>           "address": 897483456,
>           "type": "string",
>           "value": "accelerometer:didAccelerate:"
>       },
>       "r11": {
>           "address": 533964496,
>           "class": "UIAccelerometer",
>           "ivars": {
>               "_delegate": {
>                   "address": 533897520,
>                   "type": "unknown"
>               },
>               "_updateInterval": 0.1
>           },
>           "type": "objc_object"
>       },
>       "r2": {
>           "address": 533964496,
>           "class": "UIAccelerometer",
>           "ivars": {
>               "_delegate": {
>                   "address": 533897520,
>                   "type": "unknown"
>               },
>               "_updateInterval": 0.1
>           },
>           "type": "objc_object"
>       },
>       "r3": {
>           "address": 547923104,
>           "class": "UIAcceleration",
>           "ivars": {
>               "timestamp": 76274,
>               "x": 0.0708008,
>               "y": -0.397308,
>               "z": -0.889145
>           },
>           "type": "objc_object"
>       },
>       "r5": {
>           "address": 547923104,
>           "class": "UIAcceleration",
>           "ivars": {
>               "timestamp": 76274,
>               "x": 0.0708008,
>               "y": -0.397308,
>               "z": -0.889145
>           },
>           "type": "objc_object"
>       },
>       "r8": {
>           "address": 547925792,
>           "class": "__NSCFType",
>           "ivars": {},
>           "type": "objc_object"
>       },
>       "stack@0x2fd599a0": {
>           "address": 1002222760,
>           "class": "UIAcceleration",
>           "type": "objc_class"
>       },
>       "stack@0x2fd599b0": {
>           "address": 1002222760,
>           "class": "UIAcceleration",
>           "type": "objc_class"
>       },
>       "stack@0x2fd599bc": {
>           "address": 533964496,
>           "class": "UIAccelerometer",
>           "ivars": {
>               "_delegate": {
>                   "address": 533897520,
>                   "type": "unknown"
>               },
>               "_updateInterval": 0.1
>           },
>           "type": "objc_object"
>       },
>       "stack@0x2fd599c8": {
>           "address": 547923104,
>           "class": "UIAcceleration",
>           "ivars": {
>               "timestamp": 76274,
>               "x": 0.0708008,
>               "y": -0.397308,
>               "z": -0.889145
>           },
>           "type": "objc_object"
>       },
>       "stack@0x2fd599cc": {
>           "address": 533964496,
>           "class": "UIAccelerometer",
>           "ivars": {
>               "_delegate": {
>                   "address": 533897520,
>                   "type": "unknown"
>               },
>               "_updateInterval": 0.1
>           },
>           "type": "objc_object"
>       } }
>
> CrashDoctor Diagnosis: Attempted to dereference garbage pointer
>   0x31fd4078.

Answer (score 5):

It's still possible to write buggy code, even when you're using ARC--it's not magic, and there are still rules. In this instance, try running a debug build of your app in Xcode with "NSZombies" turned on. What this does, is every time your app attempts to deallocate an object, Objective-C instead replaces it with an `NSZombie` object that will provide a much more helpful error message when you attempt to use it (attempting to dereference a garbage pointer, as your silly CrashDoctor thing is telling you).